# Do you change the gear box oil on a Baotian BT49QT-9

Tags: oil

I got a Baotian BT49QT-9 Pulse. Change the gear box oil?
Some bikes only uses engine oil and it's all in one tank.

Comment: I edited the manufacturer's name and model number for accuracy. You may "revert" my changes if you disagree with them.

Comment: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/638999/Baotian-Bt49qt-9.html?page=17#manual https://www.manualslib.com/manual/638999/Baotian-Bt49qt-9.html